# Proof of monotone convergence theorem -- valid?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I came up with the following proof for the Monotone Convergence Theorem for Lebesgue  measurable functions. I was wondering if anything was wrong with it.

Let $(X,A,\mu)$ be a measure space and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of increasing, non-negative measurable functions. Then we need to show that
$$ \int \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n d\mu = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n d\mu $$

*Proof:* We begin by noting that $f:=\lim_n f_n$ is measurable. Now $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, f_n\leq \sup_n f_n=\lim_n f_n=f$ and thus
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n d\mu \leq \int f d\mu $$

Also by definition, $\int f d\mu=\sup\left( \int g d\mu: g\leq f, \text{ g is simple}\right)$. Thus $\forall \epsilon >0\exists g\leq f \text{ (g simple)},$
$$ \int f d\mu -\epsilon \leq \int g d\mu$$

Also $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}, g\leq f_n\leq f$ because otherwise $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, f_n<g \implies f\leq g$ which contradicts $g\leq f$ (except for the case when $f=g$, that is $f$ is simple, in which case the assertion to be proved is known to be true).
Integrating would give that $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$\int g d\mu\leq \int f_n d\mu$$

Compiling the above two gives:
$$ \int f d\mu -\epsilon \leq \int g d\mu \leq \int f_n d\mu$$
Since the above is true $\forall \epsilon>0$, we conclude that
$$\int f d\mu\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n d\mu$$

Which proves the assertion.

Is there anything wrong with the above?

Comment: when you say "because otherwise $\forall n ...$" you should actually say "because otherwise $\forall n$ there exists a point at which $f_n<g$". I imagine your proof is false for this reason, also because I've never seen one so simple for the MCT

Comment: For functions $f$ and $g$ it is not true that $f \leq g$ or $f>g$. So your proof completely fails.

Comment: @jcneek Thank you very much. I see that I am wrong. This "proof" being very simple compared to those presented in textbooks is precisely why I was sceptical over its correctness.